# how to blank a textbox created in the code behind in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I created a textbox in the code behind:

```
        HtmlGenericControl tdFromCounty = new HtmlGenericControl("td");

        TextBox tbFromCounty = new TextBox();
        tbFromCounty.CssClass = "rateinput";
        tbFromCounty.Style.Add("width", "200px");
        tbFromCounty.Text = "";
        tbFromCounty.ID = "fc" + this.ID.ToString();
        tbFromCounty.Attributes.Add("onblur", "UpdateCellFromCounty(" + this.ID + ",this.value)");
        tdFromCounty.Controls.Add(tbFromCounty);
```

And in javascript I am doing a check to make sure that the value entered into the textbox is a valid county. If it is not valid then I want to blank the textbox.

I have tried these so far but none of them work:

```
$("#fc"+ result.Element).val == "";
$("#fc"+ result.Element).val = "";
$("#fc"+ result.Element).val("");
```

Comment: are you getting the correct ID?

Comment: try with static id first

Comment: This is the correct way of doing `$("#fc"+ result.Element).val("");` but check your id from developer tools.

Comment: tbFromCounty.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static

Comment: Change `tbFromCounty.Attributes.Add("onblur", "UpdateCellFromCounty(" + this.ID + ",this.value)");` to this `tbFromCounty.Attributes.Add("onblur", "UpdateCellFromCounty(this.id, this.value)");`

Comment: please check result.Element value in console if it same in assigned or not?

Comment: @jonju yes I am getting the correct ID

Comment: Then `$("#fc"+ result.Element).val("");` must do what you want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#fc"+ result.Element).attr("value") = "";
```

Sorry, it should be

```
$("#fc"+ result.Element).attr("value", "");
```

Comment: In jQuery it's `$("#fc"+ result.Element).attr("value", "");`

Comment: Moreover `$("#fc"+ result.Element).val("");` will empty the textbox if he gets the correct ID

Comment: `$("#fc"+ result.Element).attr("value", "");` and `$("#fc"+ result.Element).val("");` works. thanks